# My User Model changes 'email' to username in admin panel when i update any field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a problem with my User Model. The deal is that when I update any field or fields in the admin panel, my email field gets the same data as at the username field.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. So, I really rely on your help.

Here are all my files that may be important:

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name = 'email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
        )
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, verbose_name='username')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    grade = models.ForeignKey(GradeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    reputation = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='accounts/media', blank=True)
    about_me = models.TextField(blank=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD= 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    objects = UserManager()

    def get_email(self):
        return self.email

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
    return self.active
```

my forms.py

```
class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('email', 'username')

def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    user.active = False
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user

class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password', 'active', 'admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial["password"]
```

P.S: These two forms are used in admin.py

Comment: Why do you write `USERNAME_FIELD= 'email'`?

Comment: so the most important field would be an email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is the  whole explaining of the problem

1. First:

   I shouldn't have used `AbstractBaseUser` the way I did. I should have never put fields, like *image*, *about_me*, *country* and *others* in `AbstractBaseUser`, because when you make it complicated there are a lot of unexpected consequences, which happens specifically to that model, that just doesn't happen with other models.
2. Second:

   I should have created a **user**-**profile** model connected to `AbstractBaseUser` to keep it as much simple as possible for my web application

I hope this post helped you with your issue. If it did, then vote up this post for other people